# How to send parameter while loading parent window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Plese help me in this My problem is:
   I am calling parent window by using `parent.location.reload();` after the child window is done. But in parent window I want to add `#tab3` in the end of the url which was not present in beggining in parent window.
  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you using jquery-ui tabs?

Comment: use parent.location.href="yourlocation.html#tab3" instead of reload?

Comment: NO its bootstrap tabs but I have modified them. So in that case I need  #tab3 in the end of url

Comment: Actually I do not want to give the complete url in child window. Because of some reasons, so I can't use complete url parent.location.href="yourlocation.html#tab3"

Comment: Which reason, are you already using an hashtag redirect by default on the load of your parent window? If you can't give a special hastag to your parent, supply an additionnal argument with the standard get (yourlocation.html?getKey=valueToListen#tab3) and then in the parent you would have to check if the full URL contains the valueToListen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
parent.location.href+="#tab3";
```

Changing parent.location.href reloads it.

Comment: I need to reload the parent window.

Comment: If I am not wrong it does not reload the page.  Anyways thanks I tried    this **parent.location.href+="#tab3";** before this **parent.location.reload();** and it worked. Thanks a lot.